# I need multiple instance of single svg icon

Tags: css, svg

I have single svg icon. which I have inserted in the document like this,

```
<img src="../assets/layouts/layout3/svgs/star-def.svg"  
width="15" height="15" />
```

its displaying properly no issues, but what I want is , its need to change the color , in short , I need multiple color variants of the same icon using css. Means , I can change the class & the icon should become of that color.
I tried using, fill , but its not happening. my html & css below with adding fills.

**html:-**

```
<img src="../assets/layouts/layout3/svgs/star-def.svg" class="greenfill" 
    width="15" height="15" />
```

& css

```
.greenfill { fill:#569e26;}
```

**Note**
I had open the file in editor & changed the fill color from there & have a different coloured icon , but I dont want this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should target the actual svg elements, not the img tag - if you open the svg in a text editor/ide you can add classes there and then change them with your code

Comment: Per Darren, can you share your SVG structure? Open it in a text editor like sublime.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer here

http://jsfiddle.net/wuSF7/462/

```
svg {
    width: 350px; height: 350px;
}

svg path {
    fill: yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: This selects _all_ svg's that have paths. Might not be the wisest solution.

Comment: Multiple instances update http://jsfiddle.net/wuSF7/1574/ Please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a reference with `g` or `symbol` in SVG and then `use` it the times you need with a class for each color.

It depends on the item you are working on with to color its fill or stroke and the same if you have to select a path a circle or whatever. You can select the whole object `.greenfill{fill:#569e26;}` or each subelement `.greenfill g rect{fill:#569e26;}`.

```
<svg>
  <style>
    .greenfill{fill:#569e26;}
    .redfill{fill:red;}
  </style>
  <defs>
    <g id="star-def"><!-- ... --></g>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#star-def" class="greenfill" />
  <use xlink:href="#star-def" class="redfill" />
  <!-- ... -->

</svg>
```